# Prioritize one Wi-Fi network over another

Tags: wireless, network-manager

When two Wi-Fi networks, both of which I've chosen to connect to automatically, are in range at the same time, is there any way to tell Ubuntu to prefer one network over the other?

Comment: lets leave this one visible so that autonavigation when searching works.  cheers